# Calling custom helper or library function in set_rules()

Tags: codeigniter, custom-validators

I am trying to call a custom library's method in the set_rules(...) line.

I heard one could create a class (in application/libraries) extending the native Form_validation class and write the custom methods there.

So I have /application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php with the following code;

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function test_my_method($str)
    {

   //echo "test"; exit;
            if ( ! is_array($str))
        {
            return (trim($str) == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return ( ! empty($str));
        }
    } 

}
```

and in a controller's function I have;

```
...
public function login() {                
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //echo ($this->form_validation->test_my_method(''))? "true":"false";      

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|test_my_method');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        { echo "Success"; }
}
...
```

The function ( test_my_method ) is not accessible when called in the set_rules() line. Any idea what could be wrong?.
Thanks.

Comment: are you getting an error message when you run this code? if so what?

Comment: Ok,this is what I was missing,I was calling the function without passing it a argument: keeping the username field empty all the while., but even if the function is not defined to take a argument,the function doesn't get called if the field is empty(see the commented set_rules line in the example below). So I had to use it with 'required'.

Comment: In the custom library...    
function unique_username() {
 //echo "test"; 
 $obj = &get_instance(); 
 $obj->load->model('users_model');
 $result = $obj->users_model->get_user_by_username( $obj->input->post('username') );
 if ($result->num_rows() > 0) return false; else  return true;    
} ...

Comment: and in a controller... public function register() { $this->load->library('form_validation'); //$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|unique_username'); $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|unique_username'); $this->form_validation->set_message('unique_username', '%s is already taken.'); $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[7]'); if($this->form_validation->run()) echo 'Save data'; } ...

Comment: just edit your question and add this code, formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any reason why you didnt use callback function instead extending the form validation class, for your task. See [Callbacks: Your own Validation Functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) for details. You did, extends the class if you need to change somehow from its native behaviour, not for this kind of task. Also, in addition, if you already set some custom callback, you doesn't need to include the other rule (like trim, required and so on) since you can inspect all aspect of that field within your custom callback function.

Comment: this is a very subjective comment, and one can utilize this behavior to build their own set of more advanced validation functions in a portable form to be re-used many times, instead of copying the callbacks into every project.

Comment: Well, if you build some common function, then it was other story. I am referencing to your above codes, which simply identical with 'required' rules, and theres no need to extends the native class in that case.

Comment: It's an example....  you thought he really is using a validation function called `test_my_method` ...???